# Почему код работает в Intellij IDEA, а в Android Studio нет?

Tags: java, android-studio, шифрование, криптография, decrypt

Здравствуйте, я пытаюсь зашифровать некую строку текста `encrypt` а затем расшифровать `decrypt`, попробовав пример кода в **Intellij IDEA** все сработало замечательно, но когда я перенес код в свое приложение в **Android Studio** то сработал только метод "encrypt", а `decrypt` в свою очередь выдает исключение. Подскажите почему может так происходить?!

```
    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String plaintext = "text", key = "password";
            String ciphertext = encrypt(key, plaintext);
            String plaintext2 = decrypt(key, ciphertext);
            System.out.println("Encrypting '" + plaintext +
                    "' yields: (" + ciphertext.length() + ") " + ciphertext);
            System.out.println("Decrypting it yields: " + plaintext2);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class SimpleCrypto {

    public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext) throws Exception {
        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
        return toHex(result);
    }

    public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception {
        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
        byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
        return new String(result);
    }

    private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        sr.setSeed(seed);
        kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
        SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
        byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
        return raw;
    }

    private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
        return encrypted;
    }

    private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        return decrypted;
    }

    public static String toHex(String txt) {
        return toHex(txt.getBytes());
    }

    public static String fromHex(String hex) {
        return new String(toByte(hex));
    }

    public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
        int len = hexString.length()/2;
        byte[] result = new byte[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();
        return result;
    }

    public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
        if (buf == null)
            return "";
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2*buf.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
            appendHex(result, buf[i]);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
    private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
        sb.append(HEX.charAt((b>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));
    }

}
```

Код исключения:

> Exception is javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted

Comment: Исключение мы должны угадать? Покажите полный текст ошибки.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev я только понял что это исключение но как его отследить к сожалению не знаю

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev ошибки нет код просто не срабатывает на вызове decrypt

Comment: Хотелось увидеть код из андроид студио нерабочий.

Comment: У меня в андроид студии все работает после переноса и без добавления "Crypto".

Comment: @V.March это скорее исключение, так как я нашел много таких случаев

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ найден: Заменить часть кода

```
SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "Crypto");
```